# How to parse a zcat output

Tags: python, string, parsing, apt

What is the easiest way to split a string by `\n\n` in python?

This is my raw string which comes from zcat output of http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz

```
Package: zziplib-bin\n
Priority: optional\n
Section: utils\n
Installed-Size: 116\n
Maintainer: LIU Qi <liuqi82@gmail.com>\n
Architecture: i386\n
Source: zziplib (0.13.56-1)\n
Version: 0.13.56-1+b1\n
...\n
\n
Package: zzuf\n
Priority: optional\n
Section: devel\n
Installed-Size: 228\n
Maintainer: Sam Hocevar <sho@debian.org>\n
Architecture: i386\n
Version: 0.13.svn20100215-2\n
...\n
\n
```

Perhaps any of you have ever done this

This should ideally look like this:

```
{
"zziplib-bin": {"Version": "0.13.56-1+b1"},
"zzuf": {"Version": "0.13.svn20100215-2"},
...
}
```

- Timo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Maybe someone can make better suggestions on that.

```
a = zcat_output.split('\n\n')
a.pop(len(a)-1)
c = dict()
for x in [x.splitlines() for x in a]:
    pkg = ""
    for y in [y for y in x if y.startswith('Package:') or y.startswith('Version:')]:
        z = y.split(':')
        if z[0] == 'Package':
            pkg = z[1].strip()
        else:
            c[pkg] = {z[0]: z[1].strip()}

print c.get('whois')
```

Output:

```
{'Version': '5.0.10'}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the easiest way to split a string by \n\n in python?

Use `.split`

```
>>> "a\n\nb\n\n\nc".split("\n\n")
['a', 'b', '\nc']
```

Answer (score 1):

The below script will read the Packages.gz file directly and decompress it using python's gzip module, so that should save you the extra step of having to use zcat. Then after splitting by `'\n\n'` it goes through each package details and extracts the package name and version using regular expressions. I've provided two implementations for the data structure that will store packages and their version info. The second one follows the structure mentioned in your question the first one is a flatter one that just maps each package name to it's version.

```
import gzip, re
packages = gzip.open('Packages.gz', 'rb').read()
p = packages.strip().split('\n\n')
pack = re.compile('^Package: (.*)')
ver = re.compile('\nVersion: (.*)')

info = dict([(pack.findall(i)[0], ver.findall(i)[0]) for i in p])
print info['whois']

info = dict([(pack.findall(i)[0], {'Version': ver.findall(i)[0]}) for i in p])
print info['whois']
```

**output**

```
5.0.10
{'Version': '5.0.10'}
```